# App com câmera parou de funcionar ao atualizar do Android 4.0.4 para o 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-camera

Sou novo com a plataforma e estou com problema em um app que estou desenvolvendo, ele estava funcionando normalmente no Android 4.0.4 e agora que atualizei para o 4.1.2 a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

```
02-27 10:14:47.923: E/Camera_ControlThread(156): Taking picture when recording is not supported!
```

Logo após a atualização os seguintes itens pararam de funcionar:

- Inicio câmera com `Camera.open()`;
- Configuração de `params`;
- Chamado ao `takepicture(null, null, mPicture)`;

Não utilizo a `surfaceview`, pois o app tira fotos em tempo real.

o código é este

```
Camera camera;
public Cam cam;

protected void onCreate(){
cam = new Cam();
camera  = cam.getCameraInstance(getApplicationContext(), cam.idCameraFrontal());
}

PictureCallback jpeg = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        new ThreadProcessamento(data);
        processando = true;
    }
};


  public class ThreadFoto implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    public ThreadFoto(){
        t = new Thread(this,"video");
        t.setPriority(10);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        sairThread = false;
        int count = 0;
        do{
            if(cam.checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())){
                try{
                    if(!processando && !bCapturar){//!processando && 
                        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpeg);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.v("ri","ThreadFoto.Exception:"+e.getMessage());
                }
                log = "Foto tirada: "+count;
            }else{
                log = "Hardware desativado:"+count;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ihc.update();
            count++;
        }while(!sairThread);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode adicionar um código mínimo que possa reproduzir o problema? (Provavelmente relevante: [`isVideoSnapshotSupported()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#isVideoSnapshotSupported()))

Answer (score 1):

Aa vezes o problema não é no código e sim da instalação do firmware.
Eu resolvi um problema idêntico simplesmente dando um 'reset de fábrica' isso permanecerá o android 4.1.2 porém eliminará todos apps, configs e restos da instalação.
No meu caso funcionou!

Comment: Valeu, vou testar... só falta coragem, consegui usando a surface mas ficou bem mais lento... vou testar em outros aparelhos antes de restaurar... a galera do stackoverflow português está de parabéns, achei que ninguém iria responder... valeu novamente